# objective c: getting xml file with querystring

Tags: objective-c, query-string, nsurl

So Ive built an XML parser using the tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248883/Objective-C-Fundamentals-NSXMLParser

My problem is that the XML file I am calling requires a querystring parameter. An example url would be something like:

```
http://domain.com/xml.php?id=00idcode00
```

Without the `id=` the XML file just returns a single XML element `<error>No id specified</error>`; with an id specified the XML file returns 50 odd XML elements.

My problem is that no matter what I try the XML file always returns the `<error>`. How do I get NSURL to use the querystring?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *someId = @"00idcode00";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/xml.php?id=%@", someId];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];

NSLog(@"query: %@",[url query]);
```

And this NSLogs the following:

```
Started element error
Found an element named: error with a value of: No id specified.
query: id=00idcode00
```

The last line where I output the `query` of `url` implies that the NSURL has the right querystring, but the response of the XML file suggests that NSURL is not using the querystring.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Build the string first, then the URL.

```
NSString *someId = @"00idcode00";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/xml.php?Id=%@", someId];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

And the error states the query param is `Id`, not `id`.

Comment: The message string displayed in the `<error>` tag is descriptive only.

Comment: Then it's a bad message. URLs are case sensitive (other than the host and domain). If the parameter needs to be `id` then the message should state `id`, not `Id`. Anyway, log `url` then copy the URL to your browser and what do you get?

Comment: Logging the url I get `url: http://domain.com/xml.php?id=00idcode00`, but the querystring still isnt being used, and I still get the `<error>` tag returned instead of the data.

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue on the server side. What happens when you enter that URL in your computer's browser?

Comment: I get the 50 odd elements I was expecting.